# Drag And Drop Card View

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-cardview

I have 6 **Card Views** on the screen and is there any way that i can change position of the cards by applying drag and drop on it.

I have tried the **Drag And Drop** on a **gridView** to change its items position .

I have inflated the TexView into the GridView item by Custom adapter like This:

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheeseViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);
        holder = new CheeseViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (CheeseViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.build(getItem(position).toString());

    return convertView;
}


private class CheeseViewHolder {
    private TextView titleText, filledText;


    private CheeseViewHolder(View view) {
        titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_text);

    }

    void build(String title) {

        titleText.setText(title);

    }
}
```

But is it possible to inflate the **CardView** in the **GridView item**  ?? As like every item on the GridView contains a different card.

*Or is there any other way that i can apply these Drag and Drop Operations On CardView*

Comment: for me. I use card layout and then, for the drag and drop. I use this library https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout